# How to solve the incompatibility problem of custom table tags in Outlook

Tags: javascript, html, css

On outlook2016, there will be gaps in the table using rowspan.
This problem does not occur with other mailbox clients.

I want to customize html as an email, and the table tag is incompatible. I tried some CSS, like `dispaly:block`
[outlook http://sowcar.com/t6/695/1554344627x2362277805.png](http://sowcar.com/t6/695/1554344627x2362277805.png)

```
<table style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="padding: 5px 0; border: 1px solid #bdbdbd; text-align: center; background-color: pink;">xxxxx</th>
<th style="padding: 5px 0; border: 1px solid #bdbdbd; text-align: center; background-color: pink;">xxxxx</th>
<th style="padding: 5px 0; border: 1px solid #bdbdbd; text-align: center; background-color: pink;">xxxxx</th>
<th style="padding: 5px 0; border: 1px solid #bdbdbd; text-align: center; background-color: pink;">xxxxxx</th>
<th style="padding: 5px 0; border: 1px solid #bdbdbd; text-align: center; background-color: pink;">xxxxx</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding: 5px 0; border: 1px solid #bdbdbd; text-align: center;" rowspan="3">xxxxxx</td>
<td style="padding: 5px 0; border: 1px solid #bdbdbd; text-align: center;" rowspan="3">xxxxx</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding: 5px 0; border: 1px solid #bdbdbd; text-align: center;" rowspan="2">xxxxx</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding: 5px 0; border: 1px solid #bdbdbd; text-align: center;">xxxxx</td>
<td style="padding: 5px 0; border: 1px solid #bdbdbd; text-align: center;">xxxxxxx</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Table is dynamic, it may be like this:
https://codepen.io/scheinin/pen/LaQpRV

This is the result I expected
[avatar http://sowcar.com/t6/695/1554344880x2890208949.png](http://sowcar.com/t6/695/1554344880x2890208949.png)

Comment: Desktop Outlook 2007 through Outlook 2019 (and later) use MS Word's rendering engine to render HTML emails, which only supports HTML4 and a subset of CSS2 (i.e. it's just like 1998). I recommend coding to the latest HTML5 and CSS3 specification for the benefit of most e-mail users and providing a link to a web-hosted version for users of desktop Outlook to view instead. Microsoft really needs to get their act-together on this, it's atrocious. Desktop Outlook now includes a "view this message in your web-browser" button too.

Comment: @Dai I feel the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try keeping all column (td) in one row (tr) if you want to marge column use (colspan) and if you want to marge row then use (rowspan).

You can do it by merging all column's into a single row.

```
<table style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="padding: 5px 0; border: 1px solid #bdbdbd; text-align: center; background-color: pink;">xxxxx</th>
<th style="padding: 5px 0; border: 1px solid #bdbdbd; text-align: center; background-color: pink;">xxxxx</th>
<th style="padding: 5px 0; border: 1px solid #bdbdbd; text-align: center; background-color: pink;">xxxxx</th>
<th style="padding: 5px 0; border: 1px solid #bdbdbd; text-align: center; background-color: pink;">xxxxxx</th>
<th style="padding: 5px 0; border: 1px solid #bdbdbd; text-align: center; background-color: pink;">xxxxx</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding: 5px 0; border: 1px solid #bdbdbd; text-align: center;">xxxxxx</td>
<td style="padding: 5px 0; border: 1px solid #bdbdbd; text-align: center;">xxxxx</td>
<td style="padding: 5px 0; border: 1px solid #bdbdbd; text-align: center;">xxxxx</td>
<td style="padding: 5px 0; border: 1px solid #bdbdbd; text-align: center;">xxxxx</td>
<td style="padding: 5px 0; border: 1px solid #bdbdbd; text-align: center;">xxxxxxx</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

[Check example here](https://codepen.io/pragu/pen/xeZWVQ)

## Update:

[Updated example here](https://codepen.io/pragu/pen/xeZWVQ)